# How to post to a page timeline with Facebook C# SDK?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I have a website where I can post some contents. When I post a content, I want to also post a link/description to my Facebook page.

I've created an app, and then i got the App ID and App Secret. I asked for some permissions (publish_stream, manage_pages, offline_access) and then I got the access_token.

So, I think I have all I need: appid, appsecret, access_token, and these 3 permissions.

I'm logged in as the page administrator. I gave all the permissions to my app.

I'm using C#, so, there is some code:

```
                var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
                client.AppId = appid;
                client.AppSecret = appsecret;

                var result = client.Post("/[MY_PAGE_ID]/feed",
                    new
                    {
                        picture = "http://some-picture.com/picture.jpg",
                        link = "http://random-link.com",
                        message = "A random message",
                        name = "My page's name",
                        description = "Other description",
                    });
```

The `var result` returns me the post ID.

A facebook page has 2 ID's: the User ID and the Page ID, right?

So, when I return to the facebook page, I can see the post in the **"Recent Posts by Others on [MY PAGE's NAME]"**
And then, the list of posts.

This is the WRONG place,  I want to post to the wall. 
When I click on the post, it opens a popup with more details. It has no information about the person who posted on my page. But I can get the ID of this person... and the ID is the same as the Admin ID of my page (the "person" who is logged in).

How can I make a post to my own page's wall?

Answer (score 1):

When you post with your application, you use your appKey and AppSecret as log so you don't post with your account on the page but with the "application account".

```
{
        "id": "170265327759_459817357429197",
        "from": {
        "id": "170265327759",
        "category": "Computers/technology",
        "name": "IntuiFace Presentation"
    },
      "message": "We just posted a preview video of IntuiFace Version 4.0 don't miss it! http://tmblr.co/Z4-xWvipid9i #intuiface #IFversion4.0 #preview",
      "picture": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBXteQsf4IidGU-&w=154&h=154&url=http%3A%2F%2Fimg.youtube.com%2Fvi%2FqsgXFg-6iaE%2F2.jpg",
      "link": "http://tmblr.co/Z4-xWvipid9i",
      "name": "Preview of IntuiFace Version 4.0 The IntuiFace...",
      "caption": "blog.intuilab.com",
      "description": "Preview of IntuiFace Version 4.0 The IntuiFace platform is already the world’s premier no-programming solution for the creation of interactive digital experiences. In Version 4.0 we are...",
      "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
      "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/170265327759/posts/459817357429197"
    },
    {
      "name": "Like",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/170265327759/posts/459817357429197"
    }
  ],
  "privacy": {
    "value": ""
  },
  "type": "link",
  "status_type": "shared_story",
  "created_time": "2013-04-16T10:01:22+0000",
  "updated_time": "2013-04-16T10:01:22+0000",
  "likes": 
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Roland Tomczak",
        "id": "816909640"
      },
      {
        "name": "Felipe Brito",
        "id": "578018101"
      },
      {
        "name": "Frank Coleman",
        "id": "504788100"
      },
      {
        "name": "Seb Meunier",
        "id": "1513771056"
      }
    ],
    "count": 4
  }
```

This is what a facebook page with a post look like it's a json file.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean... what do I have to change in my code?

Comment: Well, you just can't post as you with this code you should include a web browser in your app if you want to use facebook as facebook. The C# facebook API is mean to programatically manage facebook content but only as an application not as a person

Comment: same issue for me!. if u get any solution please share with me!